How to book second class train tickets in Sri Lanka?
I am booking train tickets for a trip in Sri Lanka through the official government website. The website is giving me the default option of "Air Conditioned Saloon" which I believe is first class.

I want to book second class because I do not like AC and because I find the scenic experience of the journey more direct and pleasant through an open window.
However I can not figure out how to select second class tickets in the web interface. Am I missing something, or are second class tickets simply not available through the website?

According to the Man in Seat 61 (emphasis in original):

Sri Lanka Railways 2nd & 3rd class unreserved cars cannot be booked in advance.
Tickets are only sold on the day at the ticket office, sometimes from only an hour before departure.  Turn up, buy a ticket and hop on, it's easy.  Tickets cannot sell out.
Virtually all trains have unreserved cars.  The unreserved cars are often crowded, whether you get a seat depends on whether you're joining at the starting station or en route, and how busy that day or time is.  If all seats are taken you stand, ideally wedged in an open doorway with a breeze wafting in and great views.

I recommend checking his site for further information on buying tickets, especially if you will be starting your journey from one of the busier stations he offers specific advice for.
